# Show that the set is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $(E, d)$ where $E = R^2$ and $d$ is one of $d_1, d_2$, $d_∞$ (pick
just one, I opted for $d_1$, the distance of the sum).

Show that the set $A=\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x_1 > 0, x_2 > 0, x_1+x_2 < 1\}$ is open.

Comment: Do you know anything about how open sets should interact with their boundaries?  What is the boundary of your set here?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the open ball $$B_1 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\|_1 < 1\}$$ and the open first quadrant $Q$. Note that your set is equal to $B_1\cap Q$ and that the intersection of a finite number of open sets is open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be your set and let $(x_1,x_2)$ be an element of $S$. Pick $r>0$ such that:

- $x_1-r>0$;
- $x_2-r>0$;
- $x_1+x_2+2r<1$.

If $d_1\bigl((y_1,y_2),(x_1,x_2)\bigr)<r$, then $|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|<r$. In particular, $x_1-r<y_1<x_1+r$ and $x_2-r<y_2<x_2+r$. Therefore,

- $y_1>x_1-r>0$;
- $y_2>x_2-r>0$;
- $y_1+y_2<x_1+x_2+2r<1$.

This proves that the open disk centered at $(x_1,x_2)$ with radius $r$ is a subset of $S$. Since this happens for every $(x_1,x_2)\in S$, $S$ is an open set.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1>0\} \cap\{(x_1,x_2)|x_2>0\} \cap \{(x_1,x_2)|x_1+x_2<1\}$

Thus $$A^c=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1 \leq 0\} \cup \{(x_1,x_2)|x_2 \leq 0\} \cup \{(x_1,x_2)|x_1+x_2 \geq 1\}$$

So you can prove that $$A_1=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1 \leq 0\}$$ $$A_2=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_2 \leq 0\}$$ $$A_3=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1+x_2 \geq 1\}$$are closed sets using the sequential characterization of closed sets in a metric space.

Also use  these:

> A sequence $x_n=(x_n^{(1)},x_n^{(2)}...x_n^{(d)}) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ converges to a point $x=(x_1,x_2....x_d)$ if and only if $x_n^{(i)} \to x_i ,\forall i \in \{1,2,3.....d\}$

.

> Also the three metrics in your post are equivalent thus if a sequence  $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ converges to a point $x$ with respect to one of these metrics,then it also converges to  $x$ with respect to the other equivalent metric.

Using all these and the sequential characterization of closed sets you can prove that the sets $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are closed thus $A^c$ will be closed as a finite union of closed sets.

Therefore $A$ would be open because $A^c$ could be closed.

Also note that it suffices to prove the closedness of $A^c$ with one of the metrics because equivalent metrics on a set $X$ induce the same topology on $X$